# Adding ImageViews to SurfaceView

Tags: android

I am developing game in android. In my game i have SurfaceView(i.e., GameView) which is set on    setContentView(new GameView(this));.  During the runtime i have to add no of imageviews to the surface view.  Each ImageView should listen for TouchEvent.  and now How to add ImageViews to surfaceview?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but after using SurfaceView myself, I think that this type of view draws graphics via the onDraw() method that has to be implemented. Hopefully you understand that the onDraw() basically draws things for the Canvas class and includes stuff like drawBitmap (which you can draw certain images from your drawables resources). The way I add images is just...

```
yourCanvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image), x, y, yourPaint);
```

As for listening for a TouchEvent, I'm not exactly sure what you would do because you obviously can't listen for TouchEvents on drawn Bitmaps. I may suggest a more tedious alternative which is to track the coordinates of the user's finger through a onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event).